# Ubuntu 12.10 installation error on Dell Studio 1558

Tags: installation, 12.10, dell

I have a Dell Studio-1558 which I've been trying to dual boot. I messed up with the creation of partitions and have lost the ability to boot into Windows 7. Now I'm trying to install Ubuntu 12.10 on it through a bootable usb device. I've created an ext4 partition of around 10GB and commenced the installation process. However, it's been stuck at the last step: 'saving installed packages' since the last two hours. Also, when I click on details, it tells me that 'no server suitable for synchronization found'. Now I don't know whether I should cancel the installation midway as it has already messed up my system once.

Answer (score 0):

Press Alt+F2 to bring up the "Run box", and type in "xkill". Hit Enter. Your cursor will now be an x. Anything you click would die. Click on the installer. Restart. Remove the boot device, see if Ubuntu runs off the hard-disk, if it doesn't you will have to re-install. Also check whether you have sufficient space where you're installing Ubuntu.

And the ability to boot into Windows 7 can be simply restored if you have a Windows 7 bootable DVD, just boot into and repair the startup.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Alt+F2 isn't bringing up the run box.

Comment: If Alt+F2 didn't bring up the run box, it only means that Ubuntu hasn't been properly installed.

I'd suggest you to do a clean install. Get a Rescue Disk. Download the ultimate boot cd iso from here [link](http://www.ultimatebootcd.com/). Burn it onto a cd, copy your data onto an external HDD. Remove all partitions and do a fresh install, Windows first and then Ubuntu.

And I guess you already know about the swap memory, the 10gb ext4 partition you created, that is it, you just need it to be twice the size of your ram.

I hope you've found an *alternate* solution to your problem somehow.

Comment: Btw, Ubuntu 13.04 coming up pretty soon, 25th April. I'd suggest that you wait for it.

Answer (score 0):

A clean, fresh install with a CD is the best way. Also, search for your laptop model on this site and see if this problem turns up elsewhere on askubuntu...

Try CD instead of pendrive...